# process a list of post values

Tags: database, jsf, html-table, save

I am working on a grading program with jsf and hibernate. I have a list of students and a list of criteria for calculations. The criteria list is variable and can be modified by a teacher... I was wondering how I can manage to do the set all grades for all students in a request. Let's say there is Student A and B with criterias X and Y. It should show a table

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| Student   | Criteria X        | Criteria Y        |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
| A         | [input for grade] | [input for grade] |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
| B         | [input for grade] | [input for grade] |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

I can do that, so far, but the input for grade has not a target in the controller bean since it can't be only student A and B, but could have more/les, same with criteria. I'd love an idea to manage it.

In PHP, I'd work with the Post global variable and fetch this array to get student/criteria from input name and save that grade with the corresponding student/criteria.

JSF - 2.0

[Update 1]

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombres y apellidos</th>
                <ui:repeat value="#{cursoController.grupo.criterios.toArray()}" var="criterio">
                    <th>#{criterio.criterioNombre}</th>
                </ui:repeat>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ui:repeat value="#{cursoController.grupo.matriculas.toArray()}" var="matricula">
            <h:form rendered="#{matricula.rol.perfil.idPerfil == 69}">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h:inputHidden value="#{matricula.rol.idRol}"/>
                            #{matricula.rol.usuario.persona.personaNombre}
                    </td>
                    <ui:repeat value="#{cursoController.grupo.criterios.toArray()}" var="criterio">
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText style="width: 70px;"/>
                        </td>
                        </ui:repeat>
                            </tr>
            </h:form>
        </ui:repeat>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `<p:columns>` is maybe what you need.

Comment: what if I am not using prime faces..

Comment: Loop over it yourself or create a custom component, like as they did.

Comment: Why I got a -1 in valoration?

Comment: I removed it. Your initial question was unclear. That's what the downvote is for.

Comment: ok... Thank You. I'll check the [<p:colums>](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf)